# sparkSQL filter function not working with NaN

Tags: numpy, apache-spark

Good morning,

I have the following variables.

```
self.filters = 'px_variation > 0.15'
df
```

If I do df.collect() I get.

```
Row(px_variation=nan, subject_code='1010', list_tr_id=['X0', 'X1'], list_quantity=[3000.0, 1.0], list_cash_qty=[16500.0, 5.5])
```

I try to apply the following function

```
df.filter(self.filters)
```

And it's result is.

```
Row(px_variation=nan, subject_code='1010', list_tr_id=['X0', 'X1'], list_quantity=[3000.0, 1.0], list_cash_qty=[16500.0, 5.5])
```

As you can see px_variation on my DF is a numpy.nan but after appliying filter function it doesn't filter it.
Why isn't spark sql ignoring nan or using it to be filtered?

If I do the same operation but in python the result is as expected.

```
df.collect()[0].px_variation > 0.15 -> Result: False
```

Any idea? Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special value `NaN` is treated as

> larger than any other numeric value.

by [Spark's nan-semantics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-ref-datatypes.html#nan-semantics), even "larger" than `infinity`.

One option is to change the filter to

```python
filters = 'px_variation > 0.15 and not isnan(px_variation)'
```

Another option to handle the `NaN` values is to [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html) them with `None`/`null`:

```python
df.replace(float('nan'), None).filter('px_variation > 0.15')
```